# guideline on return-by-value vs ref in C++?

Tags: c++, coding-style

where can I obtain well-summarized guidelines for *function returning-type decision* in C++?

I've known the followings:

• local variables must returned by value

• prefer pass-by-const-reference rather than pass-by-value on heavy objects

however, still, I'm wondering about what should I choose among (return-by-)value; const-value; ref; const-ref in possible development situations/scenarios?

**return-by-value:**

```
// built-in
const int foo();
int foo();

// user-defined
const Person foo();
Person foo();
```

**return-by-reference:**

```
// built-in
const int& foo();
int& foo();

// user-defined
const Person& foo();
Person& foo();
```

Comment: Non-const reference isn't comparable with the other methods, since it's the only one that allows modification to the referred-to object.  In other cases, it's similar to argument passing.  Just make sure that you don't introduce dangling references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With RVO (Return Value Optimzation) and  [Copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) you can and should return "by-value". Even for super big objects. Please see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) and [here](https://blog.knatten.org/2011/08/26/dont-be-afraid-of-returning-by-value-know-the-return-value-optimization/)

But: There is no general rule. As always, it depends.

But with the described above, you should get a better understanding.